# How to send and save Archived file to Server with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, file, webserver, save, archive

I have a local path to archived(.zip) document at NSDocumentDirectory and want to save it on webserver.

```
NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *archivePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CreatedArchive.zip"];
```

**I need to save that file at server**, then get .json document from server, change it(write there saved archive url) and upload back. I guess that this is done using ASIFormDataRequest and PHP. Maybe someone have working code to save archived files at server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do that. You can use [asi-http-request](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) to upload any file.

Use this code:

```
// Upload archive
NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *archivePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CreatedArchive.zip"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://your.url/uploadfile.php"]];
[request setPostValue:@"uploadfilefromapp" forKey:@"action"];
[request setFile:archivePath forKey:@"arch"];
[networkQueue addOperation:request];
[networkQueue go];
```

uploadfile.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_FILES['arch'])) {
    if($_POST['action']==='uploadfilefromapp') {
        $newfile = basename($_FILES['arch']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arch']['tmp_name'], $newfile))  {
            echo 'ok!';
        } else {
            echo 'fail!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Go away cheater';
    }
}
?>
```

It's working, but if you know better solution please post here.